# Подсказки типов. Как указать всех наследников абстрактного класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

```
class A(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):
    pass


def fun(a: "A"):
   pass
```

Хочу чтобы функция(метод) принимала аргументом экземпляр любого из подклассов абстрактного класса. Как такие вещи правильно указывать?

Comment: Напомните, в параметре функции после двоеточия указывается тип параметра?

Comment: Да, то что она должна принимать.

Comment: но никаких проверок интерпретатором не будет?

Comment: Не. Не будет. Но есть проверялки всякие разные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Хочу чтобы функция(метод) принимала аргументом экземпляр любого из подклассов абстрактного класса

`fun()` уже принимает всех наследников `A` в примере:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

def isA(a: A):
    return isinstance(a, A)

print(isA(B()))
print(isA(1))
```

выводит ожидаемую ошибку при проверке с помощью `mypy`:

```
$ python3 . && mypy __main__.py 
True
False
__main__.py:12: error: Argument 1 to "isA" has incompatible type "int"; expected "A"
```

Видно, что экземпляр `B`, не вызвал ошибку, так как `B` подкласс `A`.

Для обычных подклассов это работает с и без `A(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta)`. Но виртуальные подклассы через [`A.register(klass)`](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1459) или через [`A.__subclasshook__`](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1809) не работают с `mypy==0.4.6`.

Метаклассы вообще и `abc.ABCMeta` в частности пока не поддерживаются, см:
[Unsupported Python Features](https://github.com/python/mypy/wiki/Unsupported-Python-Features).

Answer (score 0):

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class A(metaclass=ABCMeta): pass
class B(A): pass
class D: pass

def fun(a: A):
    if issubclass(a.__class__, fun.__annotations__['a']):
        print(True, a)
    else:
        print(False, a)

b = B()
d = D()
fun(b)
fun(d)
```

Comment: А что тут? Я не понял.